# vue-carousel Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I am install vue-carousel using yarn and add template code copied form documentation.
then there is an error saying Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined.

[Frontend screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znjfc.png)
[console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00GyD.png)

- Node/npm version: 6.10.3
- OS: macOS 10.14.6 (18G87)

**vue component**

```js
<carousel>
    <slide>
        Slide 1 Content
    </slide>
    <slide>
         Slide 2 Content
    </slide>
</carousel>
```

**plugins/main.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Carousel3d from 'vue-carousel-3d';
import VueCarousel from 'vue-carousel';

Vue.use(VueCarousel);
Vue.use(Carousel3d);
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```js
/*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
  plugins: [
    {src:'~/plugins/main.js',ssr:false}
  ],
```

Comment: Per the documentation of vue-carousel-3d, you should be using `<carousel-3d>` as your tag not `<carousel>`. Also did you register both the carousel and slide as components?

Comment: I would agree with @Jbluehdorn - your tag does not look like it refers to anything

Comment: I have used both vue-carousel-3d and vue-carousel.vue-carousel-3d  components work fine and errors came from vue-carousel. [vue-carousel documentation](https://ssense.github.io/vue-carousel/guide/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried importing Vue Carousel locally into your component?

```
import { Carousel, Slide } from 'vue-carousel';
export default {
  ...
  components: {
    Carousel,
    Slide
  }
  ...
};
```